# select where clause in mysql when dynamic multiple values coming

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am able to query when single value coming for `$mpfid`. Now getting multiple values dynamically from my drop down. How to query when multiple `$mpfid` values coming.

`$mpfid= ['2','9','1','3'];`

Here I have added 4 values in array but based on user selection it may come 1 or more.

```
$mpfid= ['2','9','1','3'];
    function GetPfRelatedReleaseIdFromSprint($mpfid)
        {          
           $getquery="SELECT * FROM sprint WHERE `platform_id`='".$mpfid."'";
            $result=mysql_query($getquery,$this->dbcon);              
            return $result;
        }
```

Please help me how to query when multiple values coming

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IN` in your `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT * FROM sprint WHERE `platform_id` IN ('" . implode("','",$mpfid) . "')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by converting the array in to a string using `implode`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
$mpfid = ['2','9','1','3'];
function GetPfRelatedReleaseIdFromSprint($mpfid = array()) {
    $result = NULL;
    if (empty($mpfid)) {
        return $result;
    }
    $mpfidStr = implode(',', $mpfid);
    $getquery="SELECT * FROM sprint WHERE `platform_id` IN (" . $mpfidStr . ")";
    $result=mysql_query($getquery,$this->dbcon);              
    return $result;
}
GetPfRelatedReleaseIdFromSprint($mpfid);
```

Comment: out put is not coming. may be $mpdfid is getting reset and empty when we add as parameter in function GetPfRelatedReleaseIdFromSprint($mpfid = array()) . is it so.

Answer (score 0):

Try using WHERE IN as suggested in the below code.

```
$mpfid= ['2','9','1','3'];
function GetPfRelatedReleaseIdFromSprint($mpfid)
    {          
       $getquery="SELECT * FROM sprint WHERE `platform_id` IN ('2','9','1','3');
        $result=mysql_query($getquery,$this->dbcon);              
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your update but, if the mpfid values or constant i can do like this, values can come one more more dynamically